# How can i save Scrapy logs in gzip after scrapping without using scripts in bash?

Tags: python-3.x, scrapy, text-compression

Are there any ways to compress logs? I need to store them for some time for later debugging and it would be cool to find a way to reduce their size. If there is no such a method, then how to organize the compression process more efficiently?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can compress the logs after the spider has finished running by writing the compression code in the spider `closed` method. See sample below where I compress the log file and then after compression I delete the initial log file. You can improve the code by adding some error handling.

```py
import scrapy
import gzip
import os

class TestSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'test'
    allowed_domains = ['toscrape.com']
    start_urls = ['https://books.toscrape.com']

    custom_settings = {
        'LOG_FILE': 'scrapy.log'
    }

    def parse(self, response):
        yield {
            'url': response.url
        }

    def closed(self, reason):
        with open('scrapy.log', 'rb') as f_in, gzip.open('scrapy.log.gz', 'wb') as f_out:
            f_out.writelines(f_in)
        os.remove('scrapy.log')
```